# Sharing EFS encrypted

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, encrypting-file-system

I have standalone, nodomain server. EFS is used on this server for one folder. How to share the encrypted folder? Users on the server are created locally. I tried to export the owner folder certificate and import it to other users, but in this case, the folder is available only locally (eg at work through rdp), as when dealing with a network folder pops up a message "access denied". Can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Quotation from the Microsoft documentation, the [Windows Resource Kit, "Using Encrypting File System"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116.aspx):

> Remote EFS operations on files stored on network file shares are possible in Windows 2000 or later **domain environments only**.

Comment: Have you  reference to the sane article on setting up such a configuration?

Comment: @cucumber Depends on your understanding of "sane". The [official documentation is on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116.aspx), only minor changes have been introduced with newer versions of Windows (group policies were renamed/relocated, key caching behavior was changed, encryption algorithms were added, a method of operation for running EFS without an enterprise CA has been introduced).